# L5 - Error : Trying to get property of non-object (Weird Case)

Tags: php, laravel, object, laravel-5, eloquent

can you guys show me what's wrong with my code?
here's the code

```php
$datax = \App\AccountsScore::where('account_id', $account_id)
    ->where('score_id', $score->id)
    ->first();

$datav = \App\AccountsScoreHistory::where(
    'account_score_id', $datax->id
)->get();
```

i got error on $datav 's line because of Trying to get property of non-object. however, below is the result when i print $datax or $datax->id.

$datax

```php
App\AccountsScore Object (
[connection:protected] => riskserver
[table:protected] => accounts_score
[primaryKey:protected] => id
[keyType:protected] => int
[perPage:protected] => 15
[incrementing] => 1
[timestamps] => 1
[attributes:protected] => Array (
    [id] => 24467
    [account_id] => 114
    [score_id] => 14
    [value] => 8 )
[original:protected] => Array (
    [id] => 24467
    [account_id] => 114
    [score_id] => 14
    [value] => 8 )
[relations:protected] => Array ( )
[hidden:protected] => Array ( )
[visible:protected] => Array ( )
[appends:protected] => Array ( )
[fillable:protected] => Array ( )
[guarded:protected] => Array (
    [0] => * )
[dates:protected] => Array ( )
[dateFormat:protected] =>
[casts:protected] => Array ( )
[touches:protected] => Array ( )
[observables:protected] => Array ( )
[with:protected] => Array ( )
[morphClass:protected] =>
[exists] => 1
[wasRecentlyCreated] =>
)
```

$datax->id

```php
24467
```

here's the error messages

```php
Whoops, looks like something went wrong. 
1/1 ErrorException in HomeController.php line 154: Trying to get property of non-object
```

here's my HomeController.php (Line 145 - 166)

```php
function getTotalScore($name='', $account_id)
{
    if(strlen($name) > 0)
    {
        $score = Score::where('name', $name)->first();
        if(!$score) return 0 ;

        $score_id = $score->id;
        $datax = \App\AccountsScore::where('account_id', $account_id)->where('score_id', $score->id)->first();
        /* line 154 */ $datav = \App\AccountsScoreHistory::whereRaw('account_score_id = '.$datax->id)->get();
        $countdatas = count($datav);
        if($countdatas == null){
            $countdatas = 0;
        }
        return $countdatas;
    }
    else{
        $data = AccountsScore::select(DB::raw('ifnull(sum(value),0) AS total'))->where('account_id', $account_id)->first();
        return $data->total;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So frustating about this code, any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you please post the exact error message? Maybe you get the `non object` error message when calling the `->get()` method?

Comment: Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
1/1 ErrorException in HomeController.php line 154: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Please edit your original post and put in the error message there. Also add your HomeComtroller.php so we can see whats happening.

Comment: What if you put `\App\AccountsScoreHistory::whereRaw('account_score_id=24467')->get();`?

Comment: There's nothing **raw** in your `::whereRaw()` did you try using simple `where()` there?

Comment: @codedge i got the json data what i want

Comment: @ZaidYasyaf So whats the solution of your problem? Can you share it with us please?

Comment: @MichalBieda yh, i've tried it before using whereRaw() but also error given.

Comment: @codedge here is the result http://pastebin.com/dQ3bECer

Comment: @codedge thanks for your help mate, i really appreciate what you've been tried to helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the weirdest solution i've ever found.

as explained above, the problem is why $datax->id can't be used but print?

here is the solution : you can using it as `$datax['id']` not `$datax->id`

can someone explain how this could be works?

sorry for my english, i hope this would be helpful for you and you can help me to answer my last question too.

Answer (score 0):

Well, accessing the data like `$datax['id']` you normaly do if `$datax` is an *array*.
Accessing data like `$datax->id` you use if `$datax` is an *object*.

Your `\App\AccountsScoreHistory` model hopefully extends `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` to make use of accessing model properties with `$model->property`.